# Retrofit OkHttp and Signpost (xAuth) on Android

Tags: android, retrofit, xauth, okhttp

I was wondering if its possible to be able to use Retrofit with OkHttp to make a xAuth post call, with the hashed body of the cass as part of the oauth headers.

I have a basic implementation working for get requests, which do not have a body, however the service request fails on post requests which contain a body(where the oauth header which is the hashed body) is being passed through.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, basically I used used a combination of URLClient and OkClient to be able to manipulate where I sign my request.

Comment: Can you please provide an example how you used Retrofit and Signpost together? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure thing, here you go: https://gist.github.com/akshaydashrath/10119943, let me know if you need anymore help

Comment: Thanks @akshaydashrath. Which library do you use to sign OAuth requests? I see in your code "RequestSigner". 

I am currently using Signpost for OAuth 1.0. Here is what I did to use Retrofit + Signpost. 

https://github.com/asantibanez/vimofit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/asantibanez/vimofit/clients/SignpostClient.java

You instance this client with all your tokens and pass it to a Retrofit RestAdapter.

Comment: RequestSigner is nothing but some abstraction around signpost :)